# Build a Kafka Stream that returns the list of distinct ids into time interval

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have a kafka stream of objects events:

```
KStream<String, VehicleEventTO> stream = builder.stream("mytopic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(MyObjectEvent.class)));
```

Each `ObjectEvent` has a property `idType` (Long). I need to build a Stream that returns distinct `idTypes` into time interval (For example: 10 minutes).
It's possible, using KafkaStream DSL? I don't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your use case you are looking for a Windowed aggregation. Kafka streams DSL has TimeWindowedKStream or SessionWindowdKStream which should be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know `KafkaStream`'s API, but regarding general streaming api,
you'd have a method that buffers messages over time (like `buffer`, `groupedWithin`, or something similar) where you can specify time (and/or maximum messages).

Then your stream would be something like:

```java
KStream stream = builder.stream("mytopic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(MyObjectEvent.class)))
    .map(record -> record.value().getId()) // assuming you get a stream of records, I don't know the KafkaStreams api
    .groupedWithin(Duration.ofMinutes(10)) // <-- pseudocode, search for correct method
```

Then you'd get a stream that contains the ids over time.